# How to disable Email client specific(gmail,outlook) Automatic content in the email

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I added following code =>

```
<span style="font-size:12px;"><b>Name:</b></span></font><font size="1"><span style="font-size:12px;"> Pratik</span>
```

But in browser it is rendering as follows(in outlook) ,which i dont want.

```
<span style="font-size:13px;">
<div style="margin-top:14pt;margin-bottom:1em;"><br>

<font size="1"><span style="font-size:12px;"><b>Name:</b></span></font><font size="1"><span style="font-size:12px;"> Pratik</span></font></div>

</span>
```

Also in Gmail , instead of   There is

So unnecessarily space is wasted .I dont want the email client specific output ,But only the content i want to show like 1st line.

How to do that ? Thanks.

Comment: are you trying to create a html email

Comment: I am using PHP for processing.I am using header,and footer as static content,Its shown properly as its static,But the dynamic content is having Structure around my data

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can sense the problem, the solution is to use tables instead of span's or div's because tables are your friend when it comes to HTML emails. There is an article which you may find helpful

[Mailchimp WIKI](http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/how-to-code-html-emails)